# will `CountDownTimer`'s `onFinish` wake the device?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I've recently found out that `CountDownTimer`'s `onTick` is queued until the device is woken up (or at least so it seems from some thread on google groups). But what about `onFinish`?

I'm hoping *not* to have to deal with `AlarmManager` or anything that requires handling intents, since I'm having a very hard time keeping track of all the different parameters needed to create an intent, intent filter, etc.

`CountDownTimer` doesn't seem to use a wakelock, so I'm left to assume either I can't always count on `onFinish` to fire, or it works in a different way (from what I've read, there is a better way than using a wakelock - using intents. Question is, does `CountDownTimer` implicitly use intents, or some other method, to ensure firing?)

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't wake up the device. You can try it, and see.
onFinish is actually an interface that decalred in CountDownTimer class:

```
public abstract void onFinish();
```

When you start the CountDownTimer, this is actually what happens:

```
 public synchronized final CountDownTimer start() {
    mCancelled = false;
    if (mMillisInFuture <= 0) {
        onFinish();
        return this;
    }
    mStopTimeInFuture = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + mMillisInFuture;
    mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG));
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm having some serious trouble with android studio, so I couldn't check the source code myself (though I did try, a lot)